# How to write base case for this recursive function that removes any odd nodes and their children?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

What is supposed to happen is:
remove all subtrees with odd roots (if node is odd, remove it and its descendants)
A node is odd if it has an odd key
If the root is odd, then you should end up with the empty tree

My code is as follows.  It fails at basically all tests.  Two in particular are: "Failed removeOddSubtrees(41 21 61 11 31): Expecting () Actual (41 )"
"Failed removeOddSubtrees(100 40 20 61 11 31 51 71 140 120 161 111 131 151 171): Expecting (100 40 140 20 120) Actual (100 40 140 20 61 120 161 11 31 111 131 )"

Restrictions for the problem: - DO NOT change the Node class. - DO NOT change the first line of any function: name, parameters, types.

```
private Node root;
private static class Node {
    public final int key;
    public Node left, right;
    public Node(int key) { this.key = key; }
}

public void removeOddSubtrees() {
   if (root == null) {
     return;
   }
   removeOddSubtrees(root);
 }

private void removeOddSubtrees(Node root){
        if(root != null){
        removeOddSubtrees(root.left);
        removeOddSubtrees(root.right);
        if(root.key % 2 != 0){
            root.right = null;
            root.left = null;
            root = null;
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic should be that if, at any node in the recursion, the left or right children be odd, then do not recurse and instead assign `null`, otherwise make a recursive call.

```
public Node removeOddSubtrees() {
    // if the root is already null or odd, then just return null for the entire tree
    if (root == null) return null;

    if (root.key % 2 != 0) {
        root = null;
        return root;
    }

    removeOddSubtrees(root);

    return root;
}

private void removeOddSubstrees(Node root) {
    if (root.left != null) {
        if (root.left.key % 2 != 0) {
            root.left = null;
        }
        else {
            removeOddSubstrees(node.left);
        }
    }

    if (root.right != null) {
        if (root.right.key % 2 != 0) {
            root.right = null;
        }
        else {
            removeOddSubstrees(node.right);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the root is odd this wont leave you with an empty tree

Comment: @Mitchel0022 From the question: `If the root is odd, then you should end up with the empty tree`

Comment: Although this returns `null` for the top level node, it actually does not modify the top level node.  You may need `root = null;  return root;`

Comment: Yes but it still wont leave you with an empty tree. You should return the root at the end and if the first node is odd then return null

Comment: @Mitchel0022 Um...that's exactly what I'm doing, did you not bother to read my code?

Comment: Yes that is what you did after you edited it, originally you did not. Thanks for changing it

Comment: I'm so sorry for not saying this yet, but there were restrictions for the problem: - DO NOT change the Node class.
 - DO NOT change the first line of any function: name, parameters, types.

Comment: @JohnP Hey that sounds great, just show us the `Node` class and our answer can be updated accordingly.

Comment: private static class Node {
  public final int key;
  public Node left, right;
  public Node(int key) { this.key = key; }
 }    // you mean this, correct?